# How can I emit a dynamic method returning a ref?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, reflection.emit, ref

I'm navigating the ins and outs of ref returns, and am having trouble emitting a dynamic method which returns by ref.

Handcrafted lambdas and existing methods work as expected:

```
class Widget
{
    public int Length;
}
delegate ref int WidgetMeasurer(Widget w);

WidgetMeasurer GetMeasurerA()
{
    return w => ref w.Length;
}

static ref int MeasureWidget(Widget w) => ref w.Length;
WidgetMeasurer GetMeasurerB()
{
    return MeasureWidget;
}
```

But emitting a dynamic method fails. **Note**: I'm using [Sigil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil) here. Apologies, I'm less familiar with `System.Reflection.Emit`.

```
WidgetMeasurer GetMeasurerC()
{
    FieldInfo lengthField = typeof(Widget).GetField(nameof(Widget.Length));
    var emitter = Emit<WidgetMeasurer>.NewDynamicMethod()
        .LoadArgument(0)
        .LoadFieldAddress(lengthField)
        .Return();
    return emitter.CreateDelegate();
}
```

This fails at `NewDynamicMethod`, throwing `'The return Type contains some invalid type (i.e. null, ByRef)'`. Which makes sense, since I understand that under the hood `WidgetMeasurer` returns an `Int32&`.

The question is, is there some first- or third-party technique I can employ to emit code mimicking the first two examples (which I empirically know work correctly)? If not, is this restriction a logical one?

**EDIT**: I've tried the equivalent `System.Reflection.Emit` code and got the same exception (as expected):

```
WidgetMeasurer GetMeasurerD()
{
    FieldInfo lengthField = typeof(Widget).GetField(nameof(Widget.Length));

    Type returnType = typeof(int).MakeByRefType();
    Type[] paramTypes = { typeof(Widget) };
    DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("", returnType, paramTypes);

    ILGenerator il = method.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, lengthField);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return (WidgetMeasurer)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(WidgetMeasurer));
}
```

Comment: It would appear that `DynamicMethod` does not support ref returns, judging by [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17993) issue raised

Comment: @Rob Good to know, thank you.

Comment: Am I missing something here? You can't even create a delegate instance of `WidgetMeasurer` without reflection that works as intended. For example, `WidgetMeasurer m = w => ref w.Length; ref int x = m(new Widget());` won't compile because m returns `int` not `ref int`.

Comment: @mikez The intended usage is `GetMeasurerA()(widget) = 7;` which does work

Comment: @Rob Ah I totally forgot the `ref` on the rhs in that assignment.

Comment: I can say it does work if you do the whole song and dance with a full dynamic assembly. I don't know why DynamicMethod has this restriction.

Comment: @mikez Can you elaborate on the whole song and dance, maybe in an answer? What works? I tried generating a return-by-ref instance method 
 for a `TypeBuilder` and got the same exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this limitation exists for DynamicMethod, but the following worked for me. One difference is that we are defining our own dynamic assembly by hand. Another difference is that since this is separate assembly, `Widget` needs to be public (or if you name the dynamic assembly appropriately you could use InternalsVisibleTo on the parent assembly).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var widget = new Widget();
    GetLengthMeasurer()(widget) = 7;
    Console.WriteLine(widget.Length);
}

private static WidgetMeasurer GetLengthMeasurer()
{
    var fieldInfo = typeof(Widget).GetField("Length");
    var asmName = new AssemblyName("WidgetDynamicAssembly." + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    var asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
    var moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("<Module>");
    var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("WidgetHelper");
    var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GetLength", MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(int).MakeByRefType(), new[] { typeof(Widget) });
    var ilGen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, fieldInfo);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
    var mi = type.GetMethod(methodBuilder.Name);
    var del = (WidgetMeasurer)mi.CreateDelegate(typeof(WidgetMeasurer));
    return del;
}
```

Output:

> 7

Comment: Cheers mike, this works for me. My first attempt at aTypeBuilder implementation was throwing `'The return Type contains some invalid type (i.e. null, ByRef)'` again for an unrelated reason.