# Why does `dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action)).Method.Invoke(null,new object[0]);` throw an Exception?

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke, system.reflection, reflection.emit

This seems to work, providing a (weird) way to call an `Action`:

```
Action action = () => { };
action.Method.Invoke(action.Target, new object[0]);
```

This seems to work, providing a (helpful) way to create an `Action`:

```
var action = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action)) as Action;
action();
```

However, this throws an `Exception`:

```
var action = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action)) as Action;
action.Method.Invoke(action.Target, new object[0]);  // Throws exception
```

> MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.

**Question:**  Why is the above code snippet throwing an `Exception`?

---

#### Working code example

```
var dynamicMethod = new System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod(
            ""
        ,   typeof(void)
        ,   new Type[0]
    );

var ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);
var action = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action)) as Action;

try
{
    action.Method.Invoke(action.Target, new object[0]);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

This causes the `Console` to write:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
System.ArgumentException: MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.
Parameter name: this
  at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.RTDynamicMethod.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
  [...]
```

---

#### Thoughts

I've tried a bunch of variations on calling `action.Method.Invoke()`, but all sorts of variations on the call arguments don't seem to change the exception-message,

> MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.

My guess is that `action.Method` isn't a "*runtime MethodInfo*", despite being a "*MethodInfo*".  I'm not really sure what the distinction between a runtime-`MethodInfo` and a non-runtime-`MethodInfo` might be, though.

Comment: Don't you need to create a type and get the method info from that? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45317665/3181933)?

Comment: @John I haven't tested, but that might work?  I mean, this is one of those situations where I have a workaround, so I don't really need a solution so much as I want to figure out why this particular approach unexpectedly fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MethodInfo` is an abstract type, which has several implementations.

One of them is the internal type `System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo`. This is what you get when you reflect the methods of existing runtime types:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString").GetType().FullName); // System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
```

On the other hand, `DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate` uses another implementation of `MethodInfo`:

```
Console.WriteLine(action.Method.GetType().FullName); // System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod+RTDynamicMethod
```

And it seems it does not support invocation by `MethodInfo.Invoke`.

But if you cannot use the `Invoke` method of your created delegate for some reason (because you don't know the exact delegate type, for example), you still can use the `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` method (however, dynamic invocation of a delegate is almost as slow as the reflection API):

```
Delegate del = action; // let's assume you don't know the delegate type
del.DynamicInvoke(); // slow as hell but works without throwing an exception
```